# Create comment system with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

I'm trying to create a comment system with reply functionality to each comment.In the past O wrote this comment system with native php but now when I'm trying to rewrite it with codeigniter there is some problems with that.

When I wrote this comment system with native php I had a HTML file with this piece of code :

```
<?php
                $q = "SELECT * FROM productcomments WHERE productId = '$getProductId' AND parentid='0' AND isconfrim!=0";
                $r = mysqli_query($xcon, $q);
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)):
                    getComments($row);
                endwhile;
?>
```

And this was the `getComments()` function :

```
function getComments($row){
global $xcon;
echo "<li class='comment' id='" . $row['commentId'] . "'>";
echo "<div class='commentInfo'>";
echo "<div class='aut'>" . $row['userName'] . "</div>";
echo "<div class='timestamp'>&nbsp;-&nbsp;" . $row['date'] . "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='comment_body'>" . $row['comment'] . "</div>";
echo "<a href='#comment_form' class='reply' id='" . $row['commentId'] . "'>پاسخ به این نظر</a>";
$q = "SELECT * FROM productcomments WHERE parentid = " . $row['commentId'] . " AND isconfrim=1";
$r = mysqli_query($xcon, $q);
if (mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0) {
    echo "<ul>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
        getComments($row);
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
echo "</li>";
}
```

Now when I'm trying to rewrite above code with codeigniter framework I have some problem in my `view` file.But first see my `Controller` :

```
public function detail($product_id){
    $data['comments'] = $this->products_model->get_comments($product_id);
    $this->load->view('pages/product-detail', $data));
}
```

and my `Model`:

```
  public function get_comments($product_id){
    $this->db->where('product_id', $product_id);
    $this->db->where('is_confirm', '1');
    $query = $this->db->get('xbl_product_comments');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

But the problem is here.What should I code instead of `???` ? I php native I just re-call my `getComments` function, but what can I do here ? What can I do to get comments that have `parent_id` ?

```
<?php foreach ($comments as $comment) { ?>
            <li class='comment' id='<?php echo $comment['id'] ?>'>
                <div class='commentInfo'>
                    <div class='aut'><?php echo $comment['user_name'] ?></div>
                    <div class='timestamp'>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<?php echo $comment['date'] ?></div>
                </div>
                <div class='comment_body'><?php echo $comment['comment'] ?></div>
                <a href='#comment_form' class='reply' id='<?php echo $comment['id'] ?>'>reply</a>
                <?php if ($comment['parent_id']) { ?>
                    <ul>
                        ??? // What should I code here ?
                    </ul>
                <?php } ?>
            </li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: can you give your table structure and ten demo data of that tables?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can try to fetch comments data. One idea is you can call your model function to get comments in your view file e.g.

```
            <?php if ($comment['parent_id']) { ?>
                <ul>
                    $this->products_model->get_comments($parent_id);
                </ul>
            <?php } ?>
```

Another idea is to make changes to your get_comments model function to include all the parent child data...

```
  public function get_comments($product_id){
    $this->db->where('product_id', $product_id);
    $this->db->where('is_confirm', '1');
    $query = $this->db->get('xbl_product_comments');
    $data = array();
    foreach($query->result_array() as $row) {
        $data[] = $row;
        if($row['parent_id'] != 0) { 
            $data = $this->get_comments($parent_id);
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

please note i haven't tested it so it may have errors. just change it as per your needs.

One more idea is to simply create a helper function to get comments

```
 function get_comments($product_id){
    $ci = &get_instance();    
    $ci->db->where('product_id', $product_id);
    $ci->db->where('is_confirm', '1');
    $query = $ci->db->get('xbl_product_comments');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

then simply call this function in your views as you were doing in your 'native' php app.